# Can't access jenkins remotely

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins on my remote server.

If I do at the server:

```
wget http://server.url:8080
```

I get the page without any problem. At my computer, I get that:

```
--2014-01-09 14:11:33--  http://server.url:8080/
Resolving server.url (server.url)... 54.205.148.55
Connecting to server.url (server.url)|54.205.148.55|:8080... faied: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

I already tried changing --httpListenAddress= parameter at config file (I set it to 0.0.0.0) and nothing happens. It's installed on an Ubuntu 12.04 and it has Apache running on port 80.

Any idea?

Thanks!

EDIT: I also tried with no result disabling iptables and ufw.

Answer (score 0):

From your output it looks like you are trying to connect on port 8080, but you said that you have apache listening on port 80.

If the port mismatch is not the issue it is probably another firewall blocking your traffic.

Can you run a telnet from your computer to the Jenkins server and see if you can connect?

```
telnet 54.205.148.55 8080
```

or

```
telnet 54.205.148.55 80
```

Depending on which port you are actually listening on.

Comment: Thanks. Apache it's serving another web page. At port 80, the connection it's closed by foreign host and at post 8080 I get: "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out".

Comment: Can you verify that there are no other firewalls between your local machine and your server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check  the bind IP address of Jenkins, if you want to access your Jenkins from outside it should be `0.0.0.0:8080` or `YOUR_SERVER_IP:8080`

Check using the command: `netstat -tunlp`

Stop the firewall: `systemctl stop ufw`